# Finding an element of the vector in text R

Tags: r, string, text, stringr, grepl

I want to search for text within text in a dataframe. Problem looks following:

I have mock-up `thesaurus` of species names and `data` containing abstracts where I want to search and identify if any of the species names are included. I also want to identify if they contain year 2009 and 2007 - I am successfully using `grepl()` function for that.

What I would like to achieve is to browse abstracts for species names and indicate in a new column a list of species that are mentioned in the abstracts. My thesaurus file helps with that. Once species is identified, I want to indicate in a new column its `ID` for simplicity of analysis.
So for example, in `data$Abstract[1]` we have `potato blight`. I want to return in `data$Species` value `276` which correspond to species `ID`.
If there are more than one species listed, then this should be separated by column.

```
thesaurus <- data.frame(ID = c(1234,276,875,934,652,567,791,6823,467,267,113),
                    common_name_1 = c("foofly", "blight","rust","stem rust","leaf rust", 
                                      "canker", "curl","leaf mosaic", "necrosis", 
                                      "dieback","foo_abc"),
                    common_name_2 = c("asian foofly", "potato blight","purple rust",
                                      "stem red rust","asian leaf yellow rust", 
                                      "citrus canker", NA,"cassava leaf mosaic", 
                                      "cassava necrosis", "wheat dieback", "foo common"),
                    latin_name_1 = c("Abacarus hystrix", "Abutilon theophrasti", 
                               "Acanthospermum hispidum", "Acaropsellina docta", 
                               "Acaropsellina sollers","Acarus siro",
                               "Aceria tosichella","ceratitis capitata","bactrocera dorsalis","bactrocera zonata", "foosarius abamic"),
                    latin_name_2 = c("A. hystrix", "Achillea biebersteinii", "Achillea micrantha",
                             "Achillea millefolium", "Achyranthes aspera",
                             "Acidovorax avenae subsp. avenae", NA,NA,
                             "Acyrthosiphon pisum", NA, "foosarius abicum"))

data <- data.frame(Record_ID = seq(1,10,1),
                   theme = c("ag sciences; public health; veterinary sci",
                             "ag sciences; pathology, breeding",
                             "ag sciences; veterinary sci, virology",
                             "ag science; molecular biology",
                             "veterinary sci; epidemiology",
                             "epidemiology, mathematical biology",
                             "breeding; ag sciences",
                             "human health; public health; network analysis",
                             "human health; ag sciences",
                             "ag sciences; virology; epidemiology"),
                   Abstract = c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2009, potato blight consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                                 "Lorem ipsum 2007 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor Achillea biebersteinii et potato blight et dolore magna aliqua.",
                                 "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2003, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                                 "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 2009 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                                 "Lorem ipsum dolor sit rust 2001, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut Acaropsellina docta et dolore magna aliqua.",
                                 "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 2007 incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                                 "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                                 "Lorem ipsum dolor 2004 sit amet, consectetur 1987 adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                                 "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do Achillea biebersteinii tempor Acyrthosiphon pisum ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                                 "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2009, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor Acyrthosiphon pisum ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")
                   )

data$year_2009 <- rep(NA,nrow(data))
data$year_2007 <- rep(NA,nrow(data))
data$ID <- rep(NA,nrow(data))

for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  data$year_2009[i] <- ifelse(grepl("2009",data$Abstract[i])== TRUE,1,0)
  data$year_2007[i] <- ifelse(grepl("2007",data$Abstract[i])== TRUE,1,0)
  data$ID[i] <- ifelse(grepl(thesaurus,data$Abstract[i])== TRUE,1,0) ## this doesn't work
}
```

Comment: There is something wrong with the code. You need to close the ( ) for the first data frame.

Comment: First you do not need for loops. eg just do `data$year_2009 <- +grepl("2009",data$Abstract)`

Answer (score 1):

For the years columns vectorized instructions solve the problem without `for` loops. As for the names, a `mapply` and in it a `sapply` loop output a matrix of `ID`.

```r
data$year_2007 <- as.integer(grepl("2007", data$Abstract))
data$year_2009 <- as.integer(grepl("2009", data$Abstract))

mapply(\(x, Abstract, ID) {
  y <- sapply(x, \(pattern) {
    grepl(pattern, Abstract)
  })
  i <- rowSums(y, na.rm = TRUE) > 0
  out <- rep(NA, length(x))
  out[i] <- ID[i]
  out
}, thesaurus[-1], MoreArgs = list(Abstract = data$Abstract, ID = thesaurus$ID))
#>       common_name_1 common_name_2 latin_name_1 latin_name_2
#>  [1,]          1234          1234           NA           NA
#>  [2,]           276           276           NA          276
#>  [3,]            NA            NA           NA           NA
#>  [4,]            NA            NA           NA           NA
#>  [5,]           652            NA          652           NA
#>  [6,]            NA            NA           NA           NA
#>  [7,]            NA            NA           NA           NA
#>  [8,]            NA            NA           NA           NA
#>  [9,]            NA            NA           NA          467
#> [10,]            NA            NA           NA          267
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you - this works! One issue remains. In `data$Abstract` I have two incidences of `latin_name_2` and I would like to capture both (or three if that happens). What would you recommend to do?

Comment: Actually, I realised this is not doing what it should. I would like to attach this information to `data`. So in this way, I know that in a particular row, in the abstract, I have the following species mentioned - and identifying it by `ID`.

Comment: @MIH In the example data you posted, both `thesaurus` and `data` have the same number of rows, 5. Can you post **one** data set with, say `data` with 7 or 8? No need for more.

Comment: I added one extra value to data, so now it has 11 rows.